# Can a QT window be completely styled, including the menu bar when running on Windows 7 or Vista?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I noticed that the sample apps from QT show their menu bar as opaque, and with a color that doesn't match any of the styling on the window. It seems as if the windows being created by QT when running on Vista or Windows 7 don't pick up the translucency that are no the mainstay of the new Windows look and feel. Is there a way to override this in QT, or even have a custom painted menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 7 there is a special flag that activates the "Glass" Look&Feel:

Here is some more detailed information:
http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/09/15/using-blur-behind-on-windows/

[Screenshot http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/blurbehind2.png](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/blurbehind2.png)

From what I see, only the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` flag is involved.

Answer (score 1):

All of my Qt applications look  native on Vista/Win7, including the "glass" frame. This is all by default.

I must admit I don't know where you got this idea that they don't. Here's what the Browser demo that comes with Qt looks like on my Win7 machine.

[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/5535/qtacrossplatformapplica.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/5535/qtacrossplatformapplica.png)

I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Look at your menu bar, with the light blueish/violet background gradient. That should be translucent or it should share the grayish color/gradient of the scrollbar and other controls like the toolbar. It looks very out of place.

Comment: Try adding the flag from the previous answer. Then post the screenshot. Would be curious to see if your menu is now transparent. I personally don't think it looks *bad* per say, but it doesn't look "correct" either.